# Use jQuery to scroll all the way down

Tags: jquery

I've got some list items that get shown when the user clicks a button, the button is at the very bottom of the page, so if the user clicks a few times they are forced to continue scrolling down to see the button.

I want to set the scroll bar to the very bottom when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked better than the javascript version, which stopped scrolling down.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use jQuery for this:

```
window.scroll(0, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
```

Comment: I can't seem to find a property that is W3C standard (clientHeight, scrollHeight, innerHeight and offsetHeight are all non-standard), but I'd recommend against using `document.height` because although it's also non-standard, it's being deprecated and removed from Firefox soon. http://mzl.la/ewNQYQ

Comment: @Delan Azabani, I like answers that get the job done, jQuery is usually a quicker & cleaner way to write javascript which is "+1" in my opinion.

Comment: *giggles from 2020 when no one wants to use jquery anymore*